# How to change the date format in the textbox

Tags: vb.net

Code below show date in format 02/15/2012. how to change it to 15/02/2012

```
Private Sub Calendar_DateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
     ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) _
     Handles Calendar.DateChanged
 TxtStock_Date.Text = Calendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString
 Calendar.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
TxtStock_Date.Text = Calendar.SelectionStart.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Comment: tq sticky..i t work as originally i do it TxtStock_Date.Text = Calendar.SelectionStart.ToString("DD.mm.yyyy"). my bad